# SQL Query performance in Subquery

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if there is a way to do this query and get the result in a faster way than its built now. Maybe with left join or so? am not sure?

```
SELECT cs_plz                                                                plz 
   , 
   cs_place 
   place, 
   cs_companies                                                          cmp 
   , 
   cs_businesscat 
   bc, 
   cs_trgtappm 
   goal, 
   cs_repeated                                                           rpt 
   , 
   (SELECT Count(call_id) 
    FROM   calls 
    WHERE  time_of_call > cs_assigndate 
           AND time_of_call < cs_lastactivate 
           AND call_sector = cs_id) 
   calls, 
   (SELECT Count(app_id) 
    FROM   appointments 
    WHERE  app_created > cs_assigndate 
           AND app_created < cs_lastactivate 
           AND app_callingnr IN ((SELECT c.calling_number 
                                  FROM   calls c 
                                  WHERE  c.time_of_call > cs_assigndate 
                                         AND c.time_of_call < 
                                             cs_lastactivate 
                                         AND c.call_sector = cs_id))) 
   appm, 
   (SELECT Count(sale_id) 
    FROM   sales 
    WHERE  sale_created > cs_assigndate 
           AND sale_created < cs_lastactivate 
           AND sale_callingnr IN ((SELECT c1.calling_number 
                                   FROM   calls c1 
                                   WHERE  c1.time_of_call > cs_assigndate 
                                          AND c1.time_of_call < 
                                              cs_lastactivate 
                                          AND c1.call_sector = cs_id))) 
   sales, 
   (SELECT Count(subsc_id) 
    FROM   subscription 
    WHERE  subsc_date > cs_assigndate 
           AND subsc_date < cs_lastactivate 
           AND subsc_callingnr IN ((SELECT c2.calling_number 
                                    FROM   calls c2 
                                    WHERE  c2.time_of_call > cs_assigndate 
                                           AND c2.time_of_call < 
                                               cs_lastactivate 
                                           AND c2.call_sector = cs_id))) 
   subsc 
FROM   area_sector 
WHERE  cs_lastactivate > Date_sub(Now(), interval 1 month) 
   AND cs_repeated >= 1
```

Comment: Show Create table showing indexes in place (cut and paste dont type it)

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your query is fine and might even be better than `left join`s.  This query would benefit from composite indexes.  An obvious one is `area_sector(cs_lastactivate, cs_repeated)` or `area_sector(cs_repeated, cs_lastactivate)` depending on which column is more selective (i.e. chooses the fewest number of rows).

Another obvious index is:  `calls(call_sector, time_of_call, calling_number)`.

Then indexes on `appointments(app_created, app_callingnr)` and a similar one on `sales` should be useful.  It is a little hard to say, because your columns do not have table aliases, so it is not clear which tables they come from.

Comment: Yep the query ain't that horrific ... need some sonar on schema

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the query is very messy. I would suggest you to change those subqueries into views. Then you can use joins (join type depends on what you want to get). Anyway If you change it to joins, the query will be much faster because if you use subqueries, every subquery must be evaluated for each row in main query.

At the end, consider to add indexes on columns which you use in join statements it should be also a great performance improvement if you have much data in those tables.

Comment: Not much of an answer more like a comment but I'll let it fly

Comment: I can't add comments, to small rep :)